# Finding number of solutions

Tags: number-theory

What is the number of solutions to the pair of equation

$\sin({x+y\over2})=0$
and
$|x|+|y|=1$

#### Is there any general rule/formula to find out the number solutions of an equation?

Comment: The first equation says $x+y=2k\pi$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. These are a bunch of parallel lines. The second equation gives you a square, two sides of which are parallel to the bundle of parallel lines $x+y=2k\pi$.

Comment: And no, there is no "general rule/formula to find out the number solutions of an equation." That would make a lot of mathematics totally trivial. But you can develop intuition about how many solutions an equation has by thinking geometrically. It is obvious, in this case, that there are two points of intersection.

Comment: Yes, there is. Draw a rough graph.

Comment: @Awesome can you please elaborate?

Comment: symplectromorphic does it well.

Answer (score 1):

What is the domain of $x,y$? Asuming real, you have four cases, but can combine the two with opposite signs.  If they are both positive, you can ignore the absolute signs.  As sine is odd, the case with them both negative is symmetric.  If they are opposite signs, WOLOG $ x \gt 0, y \lt 0$ so $x-y=1$.  What happens with the $\sin$ then?